# Error Code 0x80070002 when debugging C++ in VS19

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm very very new to coding C++
I'm learning OOP in C++ and I was trying to write a program on my own

```
    class Account
    {
    private:
        string name;
        double balance;
    public:
        Account();
        Account(string name_val);
        Account(double bal_val);
        Account(string name_val, double bal_val);
    };
```

That's the class

```
Account::Account(): name { "None" }, balance{ 0.0 }{}
Account::Account(string name_val) : name{ name_val }, balance{ 0.0 }{}
Account::Account(double bal_val) : name{ "None" }, balance{ 0.0 }{}
Account::Account(string name_val, double bal_val) : name{ name_val }, balance{ bal_val }{}
```

These are the declarations that I did

```
Account empty;
    Account frank{ "Frank" };
    Account rich_boi{ 1000000.0 };
    Account sad_boi{ "Sad boi", -10.0  };
```

These are the objects I made in main

Edit: I also did one program(which I got from a udemy course) before this which worked perfectly
This was the class

```
class Player
{
private:
    string name;
    int health;
    int xp;
public:
    //Overloaded Constructors
    Player();
    Player(string name_val);
    Player(string name_val, int health_val, int xp_val);
};
```

These were the constructors

```
Player::Player() : name{ "None" }, health{ 0 }, xp{ 0 }{}

Player::Player(string name_val) : name{ name_val }, health{ 0 }, xp{ 0 }{}

Player::Player(string name_val, int health_val, int xp_val) : name{ name_val }, health{ health_val }, xp{ xp_val }{}
```

And these were the objects in main

```
    Player empty;
    Player frank{ "Frank" };
    Player villain{ "Villain" , 100 , 55 };
```

Comment: Aside from a probable error in your third constructor (`Account::Account(double bal_val) : name{ "None" }, balance{ 0.0 }{}` should perhaps be `Account::Account(double bal_val) : name{ "None" }, balance{ bal_val }{}`) ... what is the problem you're having, and where is the code that's causing that problem?

Comment: The way you have defined the class constructors are not correct I guess

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: also got 2 errors(both with the error code C2371)
Both of them say: 
redefinition; different basic types

Comment: @AdrianMole I changed the third constructor to 
Account::Account(double bal_val) : name{ "None" }, balance{ bal_val }{}
but I am still getting an error

Comment: I suspect that it could possibly be with the line
Account sad_boi{ "Sad boi", -10.0  };
could it be because of the negative?

Comment: I edited the post for a bit more clarity

Comment: how you can get *The system cannot find the file specified.* error here ? you not do any api call and not check any errors

Comment: It says "Error: Unable to open file" with the error code 0x80070002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding the full code which is executing successfully on my machine. Copy and execute to see if the code executes succesfully on your end.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Account
    {
    private:
        string name;
        double balance;
    public:
        Account();
        Account(string name_val);
        Account(double bal_val);
        Account(string name_val, double bal_val);
    };


 Account::Account(): name ( "None" ), balance( 0.0 ){}

 Account::Account(string name_val) : name( name_val ), balance(0.0 ){}

 Account::Account(double bal_val) : name("None" ), balance(bal_val ){}

 Account::Account(string name_val, double bal_val) : name( name_val ), balance( bal_val ){}

 int main(){
     Account empty;
     Account frank("Frank" ); 
     Account rich_boi( 1000000.0 );  
     Account sad_boi( "Sad boi", -10.0 );
 }
```

Comment: It still shows the error
btw the error isn't while compiling, its while debugging

Comment: ok im going to open a new project and put this code in, then it might work

Comment: @KAI ok, try that and let me know

Comment: @KAI atleast, your problem is solved. The mystery still remains, what was giving the error initially ?

Comment: initially, the error code was C2371 for both the declarations(see the comments for the post below this)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Account::Account(): name ( "None" ), balance( 0.0 ){}

 Account::Account(string name_val) : name( name_val ), balance(0.0 ){}

 Account::Account(double bal_val) : name("None" ), balance(bal_val ){}

 Account::Account(string name_val, double bal_val) : name( name_val ), balance( bal_val ){}
```

That should be the correct definition of your class constructors.

```
Account empty;
Account frank("Frank" ); 
Account rich_boi( 1000000.0 );  
Account sad_boi( "Sad boi", -10.0 );
```

And that's how you should declare your objects in the `main()` of your program. You syntax was incorrect.

The correct syntax of initialisation list in C++ is :

```
Constructorname(datatype value1, datatype value2):
                   datamember(value1),
                   datamember(value2) {
                  .
                  . //Anything if at all you want to include in your constructor function
                  . 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work
I'm still getting error 0x80070002 while trying to debug

Comment: @KAI did you make both changes to your constructor defination and object declaration?

Comment: @KAI I am running the exact program on my end, in VScode and its successfully compiled and executed. Make sure you are not making any syntax error or something.

Comment: I did make changes in the constructor definition and the object declaration
Edit: Ill look over the entire program for syntax errors
The compiler is telling me that I have 2 errors(error code: C2371)

Comment: @KAI - the compiler should be telling you the exact line (and the column) where the problem occurs.

Comment: its occuring on line 53 and line 54
where I declared
Account frank( "frank" );
and where I declared
Account rich_boi( 1000000.0 );
respectively